# Selenium webdriver (Double click on a search result displayed as label)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am very new to selenium and need to double click on a label(appears after a successful search result).
Please help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyzmc.png)
Attached is the page look like.

Comment: Try to do at least examples from tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Actions()` class as this includes a 'double-click' action.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='groupselect']/@option[@value='942711']"))).doubleClick().build().perform();
```

OR

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement element=By.xpath("//select[@id='groupselect']/@option[@value='942711']"));

//Double click
action.doubleClick(element).perform();

//Mouse over
action.moveToElement(element).perform();

//Right Click
action.contextClick(element).perform();
```

Hope it will help you :)